# Can you get 10,000 Mini Stars/Stars From a Bowser Space?

Tags: mario-party-series

I have played quite a few Mario games in my life and one of my favorite has got to be Mario Party.  There is so much chance involved in this game.  My question is on the bowser spaces from many of the games.  If you have noticed when you spin the wheel there is a space to collect 10,000 Mini Stars/Stars (Depending on which Mario Party you are playing) but I have never once been able to land on it.  I want to know if it is possible to land on this no matter how small of a chance.  Thanks!

Comment: Based on the [Mario Wiki](https://www.mariowiki.com/Bowser_Space), these events were present in Mario Party 1, 2, 3, 9, and 10

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well yes, you can spin and land on earning 10000 ministars/stars, but when you spin it, he just says "oh no, you got 10000 mini/stars" And then jumps away. I know right what a disappointment. :[ Mario party 3 link - 10,000 COIN PRESENT Mario party 3: