# What happens if you "Get 100 Stars" in the Final 5 Frenzy?

Tags: mario-party-ds

During the Final 5 Frenzy in Mario Party DS, one of the roulette options for the player in last place is "Get 100 Stars!". There were similar options in some of the console Mario Party games that usually resulted in the player [not getting the reward](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/173423/can-you-get-10-000-mini-stars-stars-from-a-bowser-space).

What happens if the Final 5 Frenzy roulette lands on the 100 star option in Mario Party DS?

[image: Final 5 Frenzy roulette with 100 Stars option]
<sub>Screenshot from [TheRunawayGuys - Mario Party DS - Wiggler's Garden - Episode 5 (2:12)](https://youtu.be/hGF4lXllck8?t=132)</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Mario Wiki](https://www.mariowiki.com/Last_Five_Turns_Event#Mario_Party_DS), you cannot obtain the rewards. (the yellow rewards are get 100/300 stars).

> The yellow prizes at the bottom of the wheel can never be awarded — if the wheel lands on a yellow prize, the wheel will suddenly turn to a different prize.